# how subset rows that have value larger than other values for multiple columns in R

Tags: r, datatable

I have the following `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
dt <- data.table(V1=c(1,3,1,0,NA,0),
                 V2=c(1,0,1,0,1,3),
                 Q1=c(3,5,10,14,0,3),
                 Q2=c(0,1,8,NA,0,NA))
```

and i want to add a new column that will have value `1`:

if **any** of the columns `V1`,`V2` has value larger than 2, 
 **and** 
 if **any** of the columns `Q1`,`Q2` has value larger than 0

So in the end i want to up with something like this:

```
> dt
   V1 V2 Q1 Q2 new
1:  1  1  3  0   0
2:  3  0  5  1   1
3:  1  1 10  8   0
4:  0  0 14 NA   0
5: NA  1  0  0   0
6:  0  3  3 NA   1
```

**EDIT**
In principle i would like to have 2 vectors of column names, so something like `v_columms <- names(dt)[names(dt) %like%"V"]` and `q_columms <- names(dt)[names(dt) %like%"q"]` and use these

Comment: `dt[(V1 > 2 | V2 > 2) & (Q1 > 0 | Q2 > 0), new := 1]` ? Do you need to do this for much more columns in reality? Perhaps even better: `dt[, new := as.integer((V1 > 2 | V2 > 2) & (Q1 > 0 | Q2 > 0))]`

Comment: yes, so in principle i would like to have 2 vectors, so something like `v_columms <- names(dt)[names(dt) %like%"V"]` and `q_columms <- names(dt)[names(dt) %like%"q"]` and use these

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `melt` to process multiple columns by specifying the `patterns` in `measure` to convert it to 'long' format and then apply the condition

```
dt[, new := melt(dt, measure = patterns("V", "Q"))[,  
      +(any(value1 > 2) & any(value2 > 0)),rowid(variable)]$V1]
dt
#   V1 V2 Q1 Q2 new
#1:  1  1  3  0   0
#2:  3  0  5  1   1
#3:  1  1 10  8   0
#4:  0  0 14 NA   0
#5: NA  1  0  0   0
#6:  0  3  3 NA   1
```

---

Or without `melt`, if there are only two groups of columns, then

```
vs <- grep("V", names(dt))
qs <- grep("Q", names(dt))
dt[, new := +(Reduce(`|`, lapply(.SD[, ..vs], `>`, 2)) &
              Reduce(`|`, lapply(.SD[, ..qs], `>`, 0)))]
```

Comment: to see if i understood correctly, in case i had 3 patterns `V1`,`V2` and `Q`, and my condition was `V1>1` ,`V2>2` and `Q>0`  then i would use 

`dt[, new := melt(dt, measure = patterns("V1","V2", "Q"))[,  
      +(any(value1 > 1 | value2 > 2) & any(value3 > 0)),rowid(variable)]$V1]` ?

Comment: @quant Yes, that would be it

Comment: @quant For multiple variables, you can also use `Map` i.e. `melt(dt, measure = patterns("V", "Q"))[, +(Reduce('&', Map(function(x, y) any(x > y), .SD, c(2, 0)))), by = rowid(variable), .SDcols = value1:value2]`

Comment: at your second solution i get `Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : object '..vs' not found` though

Comment: @quant What is your data.table version?  I am using the `data.table_1.10.5`

Comment: my data.table version is 1.10.0. it could be the version then

Comment: @quant That would be a bit old.  The `..` is introduced recently

Answer (score 1):

Using `dplyr` and either `case_when` or `if_else`:

```
dt %>%
   mutate(new = case_when((V1 > 2 | V2 > 2) & (Q1 > 0 | Q2) > 0 ~ 1,
                     TRUE ~ 0))

dt %>%
   mutate(new = if_else((V1 > 2 | V2 > 2) & (Q1 > 0 | Q2 > 0), 1 , 0))

  V1 V2 Q1 Q2 new
1  1  1  3  0   0
2  3  0  5  1   1
3  1  1 10  8   0
4  0  0 14 NA   0
5 NA  1  0  0   0
6  0  3  3 NA   1
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's another approach with some helper functions:

```
foo <- function(.dt, cols, vals, na.rm = TRUE) {
  rowSums(.dt[, cols, with=FALSE] > vals, na.rm = na.rm) > 0 
}

bar <- function(.dt, cols_list, vals_list) {
  as.integer(Reduce("&", Map(function(cols, vals) foo(.dt, cols, vals), cols_list, vals_list)))
}

dt[, new := bar(.SD, list(v_columms, q_columms), list(2, 0))]
```